# MySQL SUM multiple values

Tags: mysql, sum

I have problem with MySQL query. I have row:

```
id, value(float), value2(enum)
1         , 100,   -1
1         , 100,   1
2         , 100,   -1
3         , 100,   1
```

I need output:

```
1, 0
2, -100
3, 100
```

Dont working

```
SELECT id, SUM(value*value2) as vysledek
FROM table
group by id
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: So, what *does* that query output?  Because it works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01200a/1

Comment: The table name which is `table` might be wrong, it is a reserved word I guess.

Comment: What types are your fields in your database?  Are they `int` or `varchar` (or something else)?

Comment: table: s30.postimg.org/swbxhqiup/img1.png
result: s30.postimg.org/56mht1khd/result.png ,
float and enum are columns

Comment: @JakubKučera: That's the problem.  The `enum`.  You're treating it as an `int`, but it's not.  I suggest *not* using an `enum` field.

Comment: How can I repaire it with IF in SUM?

Comment: @JakubKučera: I suggest that you don't use the `enum` type and save it as a numeric type.  You can try `SUM(value * if(value2 = '1', 1, -1))`, but I think it'd be nicer to have it as a numeric type in the table.

Comment: Ok, thank you I could not figure out why it does not count.

Comment: Why `float`? And WHY `enum`? :-(

Comment: I thought that is it good. Have you better idea? I will like to for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the `enum` type.  When converted to a number, `enum`s are converted based on their index.

If your field is `enum('1', '-1')`, then `1` will convert to `1`, and `-1` will convert to `2`.  Why?  Because that's their indexes in the `enum` field.

I suggest you use a numeric type instead of an `enum` here.  It'll save you trouble and make your queries much nicer.

If you *must* keep it as an `enum`, then you can "cast" it as a number by doing this:

```
SELECT id, SUM(value * CAST(CAST(value2 AS CHAR) AS SIGNED))
```

You need to first cast it as a string, then as a number.

Comment: Thanks that you helped with my problem.